# spring csrf token from session

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hi I am using Spring MVC 4.3 version. We have using Spring CSRF functionality. `springSecurityFilterChain` defined in `web.xml` will make sure to go through `CSRFFilter` class. As per my knowledge Spring stores csrf token in session.

I have created a controller method which accepts HTTP GET call. This is the first method in my application. First time when I am trying to access the token from session I am getting `null`. I tried below possibilities only for `request.getAttribute("_csrf")` call is returning `null`.  Why am I getting `null` from session call?  Is it okay to use request attributes?

```
HttpSession session = objHttpRequest.getSession(false);
HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository sessionToken = neWHttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
System.out.println("HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository  token = " + sessionToken.loadToken(objHttpRequest));  // Returned **null**

CsrfToken token = (CsrfToken) session.getAttribute("org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN");
System.out.println(">>>>> session token  "+ token); // Returned **null**

token = (CsrfToken)objHttpRequest.getAttribute("_csrf");
System.out.println(">>>>> request token  "+ token); // Returned token value
```

Comment: Check what is actually sent - all headers and request params to be sure you actaullay send the csrf.

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful using session.
The session attribute is set as stated. But it is for the duration of the user interaction. So you don't have any indication on the server side where this came from. So the "bad-guy" code can simply ride on your session and the check will think it is ok.
The token must be part of the form data submitted or as part of the header.